# Android ListFragment error when displayed on activity start only

Tags: android, android-listview, android-fragments, android-activity, android-listfragment

I have an application that reads data from an xml file and populates a ListFragment based on that data. When the app is started, I want the list to be populated and displayed, however [it displays this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EdCcy.png)

Yet when the devices button is clicked, [the list is diplayed](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yOgsw.png)

The parsing of the file is done in `onCreate()` of the main activity, the method to display the set the list adapter is `updateDeviceList()` which is called both in the `onActivityCreated()` method in the Fragment and in the `OnClick()` listener of the button. This means the file is being parsed and the list is being set correctly, but the application won't show it until the button is clicked.

**MainActivity**

```
private static ArrayList<DeviceInfo> devices;
/*Other Code*/
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState){
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    //Get the list fragment
    devList = (DeviceList) getFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.device_list);

    //Get the configuration file
    File dir = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory();
    File xmlFile = new File(dir, "/homeService/configurationFile.xml");

    //Set up the parser
    SAXParserFactory saxParserFactory = SAXParserFactory.newInstance();
    MyXMLHandler handler = new MyXMLHandler();

    try {
        //Parse the file
        SAXParser saxParser = saxParserFactory.newSAXParser();
        saxParser.parse(xmlFile, handler);

    } catch (ParserConfigurationException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (SAXException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    devices = handler.getDeviceList();

    //Devices button
    Button devButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.device_button);
    devButton.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener(){
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            updateDeviceList(devices);
        }
});
```

**DeviceListFragment**

```
private ArrayList<DeviceInfo> devList;
@Override
public void onActivityCreated(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);
    updateDeviceList(MainActivity.getDevices());
}

public void updateDeviceList(ArrayList<DeviceInfo> devices){
    this.devList = devices;
    //Get the names of the devices as a string array
    String[] values = getNames(devList);

    //Code used to resize text views in list
    int itemHeight = 0;
    //Avoid division by zero
    if(values.length > 0)
        itemHeight = calculateItemHeight(values.length);

    MyArrayAdapter adapter = new MyArrayAdapter(getActivity(),values,itemHeight);
    setListAdapter(adapter);            

}

private String[] getNames(ArrayList<DeviceInfo> devList) {
    ArrayList<String> nameList = new ArrayList<String>();
    for(DeviceInfo dev : devList){
        nameList.add(dev.getName());
    }
    String[] nameArray = new String[nameList.size()];
    nameArray = nameList.toArray(nameArray);
    return nameArray;
}
```

**MyArrayAdapter**

```
public class MyArrayAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<String> {

private final Context context;
private final String[] values;
private int itemHeight;

public MyArrayAdapter(Context context, String[] values) {
    super(context, R.layout.list_item, values);
    this.context = context;
    this.values = values;
    this.itemHeight = 0;
}

public MyArrayAdapter(Context context, String[] values, int itemHeight) {
    super(context, R.layout.list_item, values);
    this.context = context;
    this.values = values;
    this.itemHeight = itemHeight;
}

@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);

    View item = inflater.inflate(R.layout.list_item, parent, false);
    TextView textView = (TextView) item.findViewById(R.id.text_view);

    textView.setText(values[position]);
    textView.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER);
    textView.setHeight(itemHeight);

    return item;

}
}
```

Any ideas where I might be going wrong?

Thanks

Comment: what is the error? post the stacktrace.

Comment: The is no error in the stack trace, Raghunandan, just that the list isn't displayed when the app is started, but is when the button is pressed

Comment: show MyArrayAdapter code

Comment: also post `getNames()`

Comment: make sure the array has data. code looks alright

Comment: That's what I thought, but `updateDeviceList()` is passed the correct ArrayList parsed from the xml and the values array does contain the right strings

Comment: i see nothing wrong. good luck

Answer (score 1):

You only call updateDeviceList(devices) when the button is pressed.
Shouldn't you call this elsewhere if you want it to occur before the button is pressed?
I see you invoke it from onActivityCreated. But I only see where you set the fragment definition, not instantiate it

```
FragmentTransaction transaction = getFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
transction.add(R.id.device_list, devList).commit();
```